# Does LINQ natively support splitting a collection in two?

Tags: c#, linq

Given a collection of items, how do I split the collection into 2 sub-collections based on a predicate?

You could do 2 Where searches, but then the run time is 2*N (which, while still O(n), takes twice as long and is obviously not preferred)

```
IEnumerable<int> even = nums.Where(i => IsEven(i));
IEnumerable<int> odd = nums.Where(i => !IsEven(i));
```

You could do a single linear pass yourself (refactored into an extension method here), but this means you have to drag this code all over, and more custom code makes things less maintainable.

```
public static void SplitOnPred<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> collection,
        Func<T, bool> pred,
        out IEnumerable<T> trueSet,
        out IEnumerable<T> falseSet
    ) {
        List<T> trueSetList = new List<T>();
        List<T> falseSetList = new List<T>();
        foreach( T item in collection ) {
            if( pred( item ) ) {
                trueSetList.Add( item );
            } else {
                falseSetList.Add( item );
            }
        }
        trueSet = trueSetList;
        falseSet = falseSetList;
}
```

**Question:**
Does LINQ have any native support for splitting a collection in 1 linear pass?

Comment: Why you need one linear path?

Comment: @SaeedAmiri its not really a requirement, and 2 linear passes is _good enough_ in most cases but I'm never really happy with _good enough_ performance :P

Comment: Would be nice to do something like: `even, odd = array.Split(a => a.isOdd?)`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> Does LINQ have any native support for splitting a collection in 1 linear pass?

There are no built-in methods that split a collection into two versions based on a predicate.  You would need to use your own method, similar to the one you posted.

The closest built-in method would be [`GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby.aspx) (or [`ToLookup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549073.aspx)).  You could group by odd or even:

```
var groups = nums.GroupBy(i => IsEven(i));
```

This will split into two "groups" based on whether the numbers are odd or even.

Answer (score 13):

Reed Copsey's answer mentions `ToLookup`, and that seems attractive.

```
var lookup = nums.ToLookup(IsEven);
```

where `IsEven` is a static method with the expected signature and return type. Then

```
IEnumerable<int> even = lookup[true];
IEnumerable<int> odd = lookup[false];
```

Answer (score 6):

Well if the logic is esclusive, in *your case*, you can do like

```
var list = new List<int> {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};    
var result = list.GroupBy(x=> x%2==0);
```

and in `result`

```
foreach(var r in result)
{
    if(r.Key)
     //EVEN
    else 
     //ODD
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to support deferred execution, use a function or extension like this:

```
IEnumerable<T> Split<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, out IEnumerable<T> odd)
{
   IList<T> oddCollector = new List<T>();
   Bool odd = true;
   foreach(T item in source)
   {
      if(odd)
      {
          oddCollector.Add(item);
      }
      else
      {
          yield return item;
      }
      odd = !odd;
   }
 }
```

My apologies for any small compiler error, i did this from the top of my head. Instead of even/odd, you can add a predicate.

Comment: WARNING This only supports deferred execution if you either read even first, or read the two enumerables in alternating order.  If you read odd first you won't get all of the results.